# Auditing - sp_send_dbmail from server-level triggers failed

Tags: sql-server, trigger, security, audit, database-mail

I have a server-level trigger to send a mail when a database is created. I have a  few users in the db_creator server role. The trigger fails for these users because they don't have permissions to execute sp_send_dbmail. Is there a better option here than adding the logins to the DatabaseMailUserRole in MSDB or adding "WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'"  (or similar with a lower-privileged account) to the trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ddl_trg_Create_Database]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS
declare @results varchar(max)
declare @subjectText varchar(max)
declare @databaseName VARCHAR(255)
SET @subjectText = 'New database ceated - ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' by ' + SUSER_SNAME() 
SET @results = 
  (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
SET @databaseName = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)'))

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 @recipients = 'DBA_GROUP@SomeCompanyName.com',
 @body = @results,
 @subject = @subjectText,
 @exclude_query_output = 1
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [ddl_trg_Create_Database] ON ALL SERVER
GO
```

Comment: You could also have the trigger call a stored procedure that sends the mail using EXECUTE AS, then at least the exposure is limited to that procedure and not everything in the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the ideal solution would be to implement module signing along the lines of:

1. Create a Certificate in `master`
2. Sign the DDL Trigger with the Certificate
3. Create that same Certificate in `msdb`
4. Create a User in `msdb` from that Certificate
5. Add that Certificate-based User to the `DatabaseMailUserRole` Database Role

Unfortunately, however, it seems that Database-scoped Triggers (DDL) and Server-scoped Triggers (DDL and Logon) cannot be signed (so says Microsoft in this MSDN Forum thread: [Error Signing a DDL Trigger](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1333eecd-4c66-43d4-ab8f-03511cad4174)).

But, I did find that simply moving the `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` logic into a stored procedure in `master` allows this to work. Apparently, both `master` and `msdb` are both, by default, enabled for Cross-Database Ownership Chaining, and a stored procedure is Schema-scoped, unlike a DDL Trigger. So, as long as the stored procedure in `master` is in the `dbo` Schema, it should work. You will just need to `GRANT EXECUTE` on this stored procedure to those same folks who you made members of the `dbcreator` fixed server role.

I have created a stored procedure and modified the DDL trigger to call the stored procedure as follows. Please note that I changed the variable datatypes to `NVARCHAR` and `sysname` as all of the values are truly `NVARCHAR`.

**Stored Procedure**

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SendDdlEmail
(
  @EventData XML
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Results NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SubjectText NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DatabaseName sysname;

SET @SubjectText = N'New database created - ' + @@SERVERNAME + N' by ' + ORIGINAL_LOGIN();

SET @Results = 
  @EventData.value(N'(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

SET @DatabaseName = @EventData.value(N'(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', N'sysname');

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @recipients = 'DBA_GROUP@SomeCompanyName.com',
  @body = @Results,
  @subject = @SubjectText,
  @exclude_query_output = 1;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[SendDdlEmail] TO [xxxxxxxxxxxxx];
GO
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ddl_trg_Create_Database]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @EventData XML;
SET @EventData = EVENTDATA();

EXEC [master].[dbo].[SendDdlEmail] @EventData;
GO
```

---

FYI: I just added a Microsoft Connect Suggestion requesting the ability to sign non-Schema-scoped Triggers:

[Allow signing Database DDL Triggers and Server DDL and Logon Triggers - ADD SIGNATURE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3119169/)